# jQuery pop-up with php form validation

Tags: php, forms, jquery-plugins, bpopup

i have a registration page

```
<form class="register" action="regist.php" method="post" >
                    <h3>Register</h3>
                    <div class="column">
                        <div>
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="f_name"/>
                            <span ></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="l_name"/>
                            <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>mobile:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="mobile"/>
                            <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <div>
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input type="text"name="user"/>
                            <span >This is an error</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email"/>
                            <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="pass"/>
                            <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <div class="remember">

                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submet" />
                        <a href="index.html" rel="login" class="linkform">You have an account already? Log in here</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

that use jquery bpopup

```
   $(function() {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

        });

    }
```

so when some one click register the form will pop up every thing work fine the problem is that i cant do validation to the form because when i click register after filling the form 
the pop up will disappear so i cant make the validation on the same form

i tried 
1 to make another pop up that show the error but the data wont pass to the new popup
2 to make the action `$_SERVER['self_request']`
 can some one help me withe this please i have a project for my college i nee to do it in 3 dayes

what i need is a validation for the form in the same page or another popup before send it to the MySQL script

Answer (score 0):

Make an php page ( here called validation.php ) that uses the GET function to get the info...

Then set some ID's on the input fields...

And then make an function like this:

```
function checkAll(){
    var firstName = document.getElementById("f_name").value();
    var lastName = document.getElementById("l_name").value();
    $.get( "validation.php?f_name=" + firstName + "&l_name=" + lastName, function( response ) {
        // console.log( response ); // server response
        response = response.trim();
        if(response == 1){
            alert("Everything is alright");
        } else{
            alert(response);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And change your form to this:

```
<form class="register" action="regist.php" method="post" onSubmit="checkAll();">
```

Now the key is that in the validation.php ,if everything works fine then you can echo value 1, and when something is not alright, you echo the error code ( or any code, and then with an switch clause you can dynamically add the error to your form).

The `return false` prevents the form from submitting...